# Animate UIView transition by adding it to a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, frame, uistackview

I have a custom object that is a subclass of `UIView`. My desired behaviour is to have this object initially appear in the middle of the screen. Then, after 3 seconds I want the object to transition (with a smooth animation) into a horizontal `UIStackView` that already has an element in it, so `customObject` would ideally move to the right half of the `stackView`.

[image]

I am not currently able to achieve this behaviour.

**ViewController.swift**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let customObject = CustomObject(frame: .init(x: 0, 
                                                 y: 0, 
                                                 width: 200.0, 
                                                 height: 200.0))

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.axis = .horizontal
        return sv
    }() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "first Element in horizontal stackView"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        addCustomObjectToStackView()
    }

    func addCustomObjectToStackView() {

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(customObject)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            customObject.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Post an image of how you want it to look at start, and how you want it to look after the animation. Does it really need to end up in a stack view?

Comment: Yeah I definitely want it to end up in the stackView. I know how to just animate a `UIView` otherwise.  Also, I will post an image

Comment: Here you go @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIStackView` is designed to arrange its subviews, doing an animated addition in that way may be tough to accomplish.

So, one option:

- Start with a clear "`holderView`" in the stackView
- add your `customObject` to the main view (it's now a sibling of the stackView)
- animate the position and size of `customObject` to match the `holderView`
- on animation completion, add `customObject` as a subview of `holderView`

[image]

Here's some example code to try out (note: just demo code, not-ready-for production):

```
//
//  AnimToStackViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/28/19.
//

import UIKit

class CustomObject: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let theLabel = UILabel()
        theLabel.textAlignment = .center
        theLabel.text = "Custom Object"
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(theLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            ])

        backgroundColor = .cyan
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class AnimToStackViewController: UIViewController {

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        return v
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.text = "This is the label in the stack view."
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    let holderView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let customObject = CustomObject(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(theStackView)

        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(theLabel)
        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(holderView)

        view.addSubview(customObject)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            theStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),

            holderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customObject.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            holderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customObject.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        customObject.center = view.center

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let pt = self.holderView.center
        let convertedPoint = self.theStackView.convert(pt, to: self.view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.customObject.center = convertedPoint
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            if finished {
                self.holderView.addSubview(self.customObject)
                self.customObject.frame = self.holderView.bounds
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I am in the process of trying it out. Will let you know soon